# Convert Sprite Atlas to Unity3D format

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a spritesheet and the associated atlas with data such as the name for each sprite, its position, and its size. I would like to import this data into Unity, and need either a tool or a plugin to do this.

I have researched some tools like TexturePacker, but they don't offer the possibility of importing data.

The data I do have I can export to any format necessary (like JSON or XML) should a tool need this.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json and push it data to [TextureImported](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter.html) in this way:

```
    var textureImporter = UnityEditor.AssetImporter.GetAtPath("asset path") as UnityEditor.TextureImporter;
    textureImporter.spritesheet = new UnityEditor.SpriteMetaData[]
    {
        new SpriteMetaData()
        {
            // srpite 1 position data
        },
        new SpriteMetaData()
        {
            // srpite 2 position data
        },
    };
    textureImporter.SaveAndReimport();
```

Comment: How would I go about adding the metadata dinamically? The example code shows how to do it statically, and since its creating a list, I can't just place a loop there.

Comment: @Daniel by "statically" you mean "in editor" or just "hardcoded"? if second - you can generate array on loop dynamically, this is not a problem. just parse json and add data about each sprite to array, after it assign sprites array to `textureImporter.spritesheet`

Comment: Ah yes, I managed to figure it out. I'm working on a parser now. Will report back soon.

Comment: @Daniel I will be here if need some ideas :)

Comment: My next question is what do I do with the script? The way I see it this will parse the Json every time it's run. I just want to run it once, and end up with a proper Unity Sprite Atlas.

Comment: @Daniel most cleanest solution is write editor script. You can use this plugin as example https://github.com/SubjectNerd-Unity/Psd2UnityImporter (or just replace PSD importing with your own parsing system which under the MIT licence)